# Proof of "AD + every set of reals is Suslin" implies AD$_\mathbb{R}$

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, lo.logic

Could someone point me toward a proof that "ZF + AD + every set of reals is Suslin" (+ $\mathsf{DC}\_\mathbb{R}$?) implies $\mathsf{AD}\_\mathbb{R}$, either with a reference or a hint?

I am interested how local the proof is; that is, which sets of reals need to be Suslin in order to show the determinacy of a particular real game.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.  I cannot seem to get a subscript \mathbb{R} in the body of the question.

Comment: Hi Trevor. Isn't this covered in Richard's paper (More structural consequences of AD)? 

Comment: Hi Andres, it looks like he just says it is due independently to Martin and Woodin, and is unpublished.

Comment: I might be mistaken but if I remember correctly, I saw something like this result in the Cabal reprints (in Steve's Article, volume I). If you don't have them, I'll try to check if it's indeed there later.

Comment: @alephomega It looks like Jackson just mentions that the equivalence between AD$_\mathbb{R}$ and "every set is Suslin" was proved by Woodin.

Comment: Paul Larson's article "A Brief History of Determinacy" mentions that the proof you're looking for is due to Martin. See the paragraph just before Theorem 6.8 in http://www.users.muohio.edu/larsonpb/determinacy_cabal.pdf. There is, however, no list of references at the end of the article. So you may want to contact Prof. Larson directly. 

Comment: You can find it here : http://www.users.miamioh.edu/larsonpb/adplusbook_public.pdf